# mat file to weka file

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, weka

I am trying to use weka but it cannot. I have a .mat file that I generated in MATLAB and tried to convert it to WEKA format.

Things that I tried:

1. .mat to .xml (to use it in WEKA experimenter part) to do that I used the following code in [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-xml-documents.html#bsmnj5u) and WEKA gives error and says that "couldn't open experiment file"
2. tried to convert it as .arff file to use in WEKA explorer and followed the [instructions here](http://orpix.org/2011/12/12/matlab-and-weka-mat2arff-conversion/)

But I have no idea about what `classes` and `relation` means in the code. I also couldn't find it on the internet. What are these two values meaning?

Best,

```
[ success_value ] = mat2arff( mat_filename, arff_filename, relation, classes )
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of any of the sample `.arff` files supplied with Weka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an external function such as 'mat2arff'.
Weka can read *.csv files, so you can use *csvwrite*.
So, Assuming your mat file name is *Matlab.mat* and it contains a variable named *test*, you can do this:

```
>> load Matlab.mat
>> csvwrite('yourCSVfile.csv', test);
```